# Why is `(id ^ (id >>> 32))` a good implementation of hashCode for long?

Tags: java, hashcode

I was using IntelliJ to generate the `hashCode()` function of a class for me. The `hashCode` is depending only on one field of type `long`. IntelliJ generated the following for me:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (int) (longField ^ (longField >>> 32));
}
```

Why is this a good implementation? Is it a good implementation after all?

Comment: Effective Java 2nd edition (http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683) have a great section about it.